# How to insert distinct records from one table to another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, where-clause, distinct, sql-insert

I am using SQL Server and I have the following query

```
select distinct(country) 
from UserTable 
where country is not null 
  and country != '' 
order by country
```

It returns all distinct countries from the table and it is working properly.

Now from the returned values from this query, I want to insert into another table called `lookuptable` which contains the following columns:

```
LookupAttribute ="Region"
LookupDisplayValue = country name
LookupActualValue = country name
```

```
insert into LookupTable (LookupAttribute, LookupDisplayValue, LookupActualValue) 
    (select 'Region', distinct(country), distinct(country) 
     from UserTable  
     where country is not null and country != '' 
     order by Country)
```

However this does not work; I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'

Comment: `Distinct` is a *row modifier*, not a *function* - it's unlikely you need and *order by* criteria also for data stored in a lookup table.

Comment: Query INSERT ... SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM Some

Comment: Extended Events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is not a function. 
It operates on rows and not on columns.
Also, the `ORDER BY` clause [does not guarantee the order of the insertions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Change to this:

```
INSERT INTO LookupTable (LookupAttribute, LookupDisplayValue, LookupActualValue) 
SELECT DISTINCT 'Region', country, country 
FROM UserTable  
WHERE country <> '' ;
```

The condition `country IS NOT NULL` is not needed because `null`s are filtered out by `country <> ''`.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT needs to go immediately after the SELECT and only used once.

```
select DISTINCT Region, country from UserTable  where country is not null and country!='' order by Country
```